# Cannot resolve getActivity() in recyclerView.adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions

Got stuck little bit. I tried change getActivity to 'c' (context), but then getSupportFragmentManager gets the same error. Read different topics on this, but couldn't find a solution. Checked libraries and tried to change them but nothing. Would appreciate some help!

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
 import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
 import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
 import com.example.mrti.menu.Fragments.MealsListFragment;
 import com.example.mrti.menu.R;
 import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

Context c;
ArrayList<Category> Categories;

public CategoryAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Category> Categories) {
    this.c = c;
    this.Categories = Categories;
}
// INITIALIZE HOLDER
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rec_item, null);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    // BIND DATA TO VIEWS

    holder.mNameTextView.setText(Categories.get(position).getName());

    // LOAD IMAGES FROM WEB AND CACHE THEM

    Glide.with(c)
            .load(Categories.get(position).getImage())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) // Saves the media item after all transformations to cache and
                                                     // Saves just the original data to cache.
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(holder.img);

    // LISTENER

    holder.setItemClickListener(new itemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
            Toast.makeText(c, Categories.get(pos).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            MealsListFragment fragment = new MealsListFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.root_layout, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }
    });
   }
```

Comment: Does `c.getActivity()` work?

Comment: @AlLelopath No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Cannot resolve getActivity() in fragment

Your Java class is declared like this:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>
```

`CategoryAdapter` is not a fragment. `CategoryAdapter` is a `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

[`RecyclerView.Adapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) does not have a `getActivity()` method. Hence, your code will not compile.

You seem to want to execute a `FragmentTransaction` inside the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. However, to be able to call `getSupportFragmentManager()`, you need the `FragmentActivity` that is hosting the `RecyclerView` to which your `CategoryAdapter` is attached.

But, a `RecyclerView.Adapter` has no direct or indirect access to that `FragmentActivity`. So, you need to get the `FragmentActivity` into the `CategoryAdapter`.

Your current constructor is declared as:

```
public CategoryAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Category> Categories)
```

My guess is that in your activity, you are calling `new CategoryAdapter(this, someListOfcategories)`. If so, change your constructor to:

```
public CategoryAdapter(FragmentActivity c, ArrayList<Category> Categories)
```

and change your field to be a `FragmentActivity`. Then, you can change:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

to:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = c.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? Maybe use some pseudo-code (I'm beginner).
Doesn't my field Context c contain current activity?

Comment: Thanks, but now at onItemClick method, line ''fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.root_layout, fragment);'' I get error at fragment as ''Wrong 2nd argument type".

Comment: @ThingsILove1996: If I had to guess, `MealsListFragment` is extending from `android.app.Fragment`, instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Would not that (saving the Activity in the Adapter constructor) be a memory leak?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: No, so long as the adapter has the same lifetime as the activity. If you do something to cause the adapter to live longer than its activity (e.g., stick it in a `static` field), then you will have a memory leak.

Comment: One more question please: what if I need the Activity in my custom ViewHolder (because that is where my click listener is) instead of the Adapter as in this question? How to pass the Activity to VH? I cannot use the Adapter constructor for that anymore (since it is a static class inside of the Adapter).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: Um, you lost me there. If your adapter is creating your viewholders, your adapter will need the activity to pass to the viewholders. Whether you get the activity to the adapter via its constructor or some other method is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

`Context` does not have a `getActivity` method, only `Fragment` does.

So, if you want to use it in this way, you need to change your field from `Context c;` into `Fragment c;`, and then call `c.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` in `onItemClick`.

Or alternatively, change your field to `Activity c;`, and then call `c.getSupportFragmentManager()`.